# Output of command as variable

Tags: bash, shell, gunzip

I'm writing a PBS script to process many files at once and perform multiple actions.

I would like to start by unzipping .gz files (which I later zip) and then process the unzipped file.

The following will unzip the file in `$file`, but I once I have unzipped the file, I would like the variable `$file` to refer to the unzipped version:

```
for file in $READS/*2.fq.gz;
do
    gunzip $file
    # continue script with the gunzipped file  
done
```

Something like:

```
for file in $READS/*2.fq.gz;
do
    file=gunzip $file
    # continue script with the gunzipped file  
done
```

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question? The output of the command isn't the filename. `gunzip` doesn't produce any output, it just uncompresses the file silently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to remove the `.gz` suffix on $file:

```
file=${file%.gz}
```

Note that you probably *also* want to check the result of the gunzip command to see if it failed:

```
for file in $READS/*2.fq.gz;
do
    if gunzip $file; then
        file=${file%.gz}
        # continue script with the gunzipped file
    else
        # gunzip failed (corrupt file?) and already output an error message
        # try to recover?
    fi
done
```

Comment: When the script grows bigger, hopefully not, it will be harder to trace because the same variable in the loop is being modified inside. Use a separate local variable or just simply keep referring to `${file%.gz}`.